# How can I tell if I'm on a dedicated IP in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sender-authentication-package

As the title suggests, we have SAP setup for the account but I'm not sure if we have a dedicated IP or not. Is there a way to identify this without asking Salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sender Authentication Package (SAP)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_sender_authentication_package.htm&type=5) comes with a private domain AND dedicated IP. So basically, if you have a SAP then you have a dedicated IP.

> The Sender Authentication Package in Email Studio provides a
>   collection of products designed to help ensure that your email
>   messages reach the inboxes of the intended recipients
>
> **Private Domain** - This product assigns a domain used to send email.
>   This domain acts as the From address for your email sends. The
>   Salesforce Marketing Cloud authenticates your email sends using the
>   Sender Policy Framework (SPF), Sender ID, and DomainKeys/DKIM
>   authentication.
>
> **Account Branding** - The Salesforce Marketing Cloud will
>   brand your account with your chosen authenticated domain. This product
>   modifies link and image wrapping and removes all references to the
>   Salesforce Marketing Cloud in favor of your authenticated domain.
>
> **Dedicated IP Address** - This product assigns a unique IP address to
>   your account. All email sent from your account via the Salesforce
>   Marketing Cloud uses this IP address. This IP address represents most
>   of your sending reputation.
>
> **Reply Mail Management** - This product
>   controls the replies you receive from your subscribers. You can assign
>   filters for out-of-office messages and manual unsubscribe requests.

Comment: Just had to deal with a Client where the SAP was set up on a Shared IP (by another SF firm). It looks like it all comes down to what was filled-out in the form needed to activate the SAP package! 
Though you're right in 99% of the cases, it's a direct question on the form - and SAP doesn't equal Dedicated IP!

Answer (score 2):

If you have SAP configured, most likely you have a dedicated IP. But not necessary. One easy way to check is to go to, for example, https://senderscore.org and sign up for a free account. Then you can check the IP-address from which you received an email.

Under the section *Sending Domains* you can see all the domains that has sent emails from that IP-address. If there is domains that you're not familiar with. Most likely you are on a shared IP-address.